# Rotating a UIView to point at another UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, rotation, transform

I'm trying to get a `UIView` called `object` to rotate to point at the center of another `UIView` called `orig`. I can't seem to be able to calculate the angle correctly. My trig is a bit rusty so I can't figure out how my math is wrong.

```
let y0 = object.center.y
let y1 = orig?.center.y
let x0 = object.center.x
let x1 = orig?.center.x

let angle = atan2((y1! - y0), (x1! - x0)) * 180 / CGFloat.pi
rotateTo(object: object, degrees: angle, time: deplexed[1] as! CGFloat)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the top of rotator view point at the target point.

```
let direction = CGPoint(x: targetPoint.x - rotatorView.center.x, y: targetPoint.y - rotatorView.center.y)
var angle = atan2(direction.y, direction.x)
rotatorView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle + .pi/2)
```

atan2 returns zero if point is to the right.

[image]

If you want to convert the atan2 result to degrees:

```
if angle < 0 {
    angle += .pi * 2
}
let degrees = angle * 180.0/.pi
```

You add a full circle if the angle is negative. 0 degrees points to the right.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a default object and suppose it's a button :**

```
let button = UIButton()

if button.transform == CGAffineTransform.identity {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.radians(degrees: 180))

    })

} else {

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

     button.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

     })
}

func radians(degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(degrees * CGFloat.pi / degrees)       

}
```